# Error trying to get iAds off screen

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ads

Trying to make iAds go off screen when no ad is loaded, as per Apple's request. They gave me this code:

```
- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
{
 if (self.bannerIsVisible)
 {
  [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateAdBannerOff" context:NULL];
   // assumes the banner view is at the top of the screen.
  banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, -50);
  [UIView commitAnimations];
  self.bannerIsVisible = NO;
 }
}
```

I made my view a delegate for iAds and whatnot, but whenever I try to compile, I get:

```
"Request for member 'bannerIsVisible' in something not a structure or union
```

I tried adding a BOOL bannerIsVisible, but it just made things worse

Comment: You don't get to manage iAds. The iAds manage your application. Get used to it. haha

Comment: If adding a BOOL property "made things worse", you might get better answers if you explain why things are worse and describe how you added the property.

Comment: Two days ago, you were asking about how to get started with iPhone development: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144958/what-book-should-i-get-to-learn-iphone-programming-closed , stating that you knew very little Objective-C.  Without sounding like a jerk, perhaps you should take a little more time to familiarize yourself with the language and APIs before submitting an application to the App Store.

Comment: This app isn't for the App store. I am a very tactile learner. I'm reading the books but they don't do anything for me if I can't go farther than them and make my own stuff. I'm just trying to familiarize myself with the language and iAd API, as you suggest.

Comment: @Brad Larson - I've seen the other comments you've left. Perhaps, without sounding like a jerk, if you could spend a little less time criticizing people not as proficient as you and instead help them become better programmers it would lead to better polish in applications and a better user experience. JK- Just having some fun. Thanks for the help, though.

Comment: @Brad Larson - P.S. I just found out you made Pi Cubed. I use it every day helping my friend on his farnsworth fusor. Great app!

Comment: @SeniorShizzle - Yeah, it's hard to convey context in short comments.  Writing an application to learn the platform is my preferred strategy, but it took me months before I felt comfortable enough with Cocoa on the Mac to do something the public would see.  For my iPhone work, I devote weeks just to testing updates before I submit them.  It seems like too many people want just to do the bare minimum to submit an application and make a quick buck, rather than take the time to provide a little extra polish.  I like to push people toward the latter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use `self.bannerIsVisible` you need to have `bannerIsVisible` declared as a property.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to declare it again and it worked. For some reason the add won't hide, though. What data type should bannerIsVisible be?

Comment: @SeniorShizzle - This should be a BOOL, like you've already set it to be.  Somewhere in your controller's initialization you need to set this to YES, if the iAd banner is visible on startup.  If not, set it to YES when the banner first appears on the screen.